# php doesn't get a variable in function despite a "global"

Tags: php, function, variables, global

I have a problem, I have an anonymous function in my PHP code, I've to do a `str_replace` with two variables, `$user_id` and `$first_name`. When I call `$user_id` and `$first_name` they're blank, but if I use that out of the function they works. I use "global". "$database" works.

```
$getTrans = function($lang, $identifier)
{
    global $database, $username, $user_id, $first_name;
    $mammt = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM translations WHERE language=? AND code=?");
    $mammt->execute([$lang, $identifier]);
    $trans = $mammt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['translation'];
    if($trans == NULL){
        $mammt->execute(['italian', $identifier]);
        $trans = $mammt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['translation'];
    }
    return str_replace(['\n', "{MENTION}"], ["\n", "<a href='tg://user?id=$user_id'>$first_name</a>"], $trans);
};
```

Declaration of variable user_id:

> ```
> if (isset($update['message']['from_id'])){
>     $user_id = $update['message']['from_id'];
> }
> ```

If I do

> echo $user_id;

I get the user_id, same for the first_name.

Fixed that. Thanks to RiggsFolly. Now the code is this:

> ```
> $getTrans = function($lang, $identifier) use (&$message, &$username, &$user_id, &$first_name)
> ```

Comment: Are you sure that these variables are declared as global outside the function too ?

Comment: Yes I am. Do you want to see the code?

Comment: [See example 3 in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to RiggsFolly. This is the solution to my problem:

> $getTrans = function($lang, $identifier) use (&$message, &$username,
>   &$user_id, &$first_name)

Comment: You are welcome. A problem solved by yourself is always more rewarding :) and memorable